# Contents of multiple Lists put in a Set

Tags: java

Is there a way to put contents of mulitple Lists to a Set? (Eliminating the duplicates)

For example contents of listA, listB, listC all be put in a Set. (Assuming they are of same type)

Comment: Yes, we can. What you have tried ?

Comment: How are you list declared? Are they of same type? You don't give us much information, it's hard to help you...

Comment: Do you want to eliminate duplicates from each list or from whole group of liatA, listB, listC should not have duplicate ?

Comment: I just want to combine the 3 lists to one collection type at the same time eliminating the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can.

The Set will add all of the elements from each of the lists and then remove any duplicate objects based on the objects `equals` and `hashCode()` methods. (When implementing one, you should implement the other.)

```
List<Object> listA = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> listB = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> listC = new ArrayList<Object>();

Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
set.addAll(listA);
set.addAll(listB);
set.addAll(listC);
```

*EDIT: Did Some Testing*

Here's a little test method that shows this in action:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String one = new String("one");
    final String two = new String("two");
    final String three = new String("three");
    final String four = new String("four");

    final List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
    listA.add(one);
    listA.add(two);

    final List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    listB.add(two);
    listB.add(three);

    final List<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();
    listC.add(three);
    listC.add(four);

    final Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.addAll(listA);
    set.addAll(listB);
    set.addAll(listC);

    System.out.println(set);
}
```

And the output is:

> [two, one, three, four]

This shows the implementation working, but you should obviously keep in mind that the order of the remaining objects might not be want you anticipate or desire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may declare a set of lists, if that's what you're looking for.

```
Set<List<SomeType>> mySet = new Set<>();
mySet.add(listA);
mySet.add(listB);
mySet.add(listC);
```